# Android NDK - Logging float c++ side

Tags: android, android-ndk

In android Studio NDK c++ side using this command  `__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "soumetag", "test = %d",  (0.1));` for logging I'm unable to log float variables, how can I display also float values using this command? already tied different type of casting without any result.

Comment: So you tried "test = %f" since it is supposed to support [printf(3) formatting](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/logging#__android_log_print)